# Independant vs disjoint paths

Tags: graph-theory

In the Diestel's book about Graph Theory, the two terms seem to be used interchangeably. 
The term *disjoint paths* is not defined, but *independant paths* is defined to be "two paths that do not have internal vertices in common".

On wikipedia, only *vertex-independent* (synonym of *internally vertex-disjoint*) and *edge-independant* (synonym of *internally edge-disjoint*) are defined.

If I understood correctly what this implies, I'd say that two paths are disjoint if they do not share **any** vertice, and independant if they do not share any **internal** vertices (i.e. they can have the same endpoints).

Am I right?

Comment: It might also be that the may share vertices, but cannot share edges.

Comment: @christophetd: Your understanding is correct. I know (and like) Diestel's book very much. If you have more questions: just ask.